# Loading javascript with MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The following view is giving me "Object doesn't support prop or method jCarouselLite".  I have an almost identical page using plain html which works.  Am I loading the javascript properly?

```
@using System.Web.Script.Services
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jcarousellite_1.0.2.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Add Carousel plugin to rotate images
        $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
            visible: 1,
            auto: 3000,
            speed: 800,
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });

    });
</script>

<button class="prev"><<</button>
<button class="next">>></button>
<div class="anyClass">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="/gallery/slide-1.jpg" width="250" height="150"></li>
        <li><img src="/gallery/slide-2.jpg" width="250" height="150"></li>
        <li><img src="/gallery/slide-3.jpg" width="250" height="150"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you've got an answer below. One more tip I would like to tell you. It is always add your custom scripts in a bundle. It will make Shared Layout look very clean.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your jcarousellite jquery plugin does't load. One possible reason is that it hasn't ~ sign

```
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jcarousellite_1.0.2.js")"></script>
```

And it should be this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jcarousellite_1.0.2.js")"></script>
```

If your page isn't located in the root of site, then it can doesn't find it.

You can check in browser Developer tools, what is the url for JQuery and what is for jcarousellite plugin. I suppose they will be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using System.Web.Script.Services
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jcarousellite_1.0.2.js")"></script>

    enter code here

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Add Carousel plugin to rotate images
        $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
            visible: 1,
            auto: 3000,
            speed: 800,
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });

    });
</script>

<button class="prev"><<</button>
<button class="next">>></button>
<div class="anyClass">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="/gallery/slide-1.jpg" width="250" height="150"></li>
        <li><img src="/gallery/slide-2.jpg" width="250" height="150"></li>
        <li><img src="/gallery/slide-3.jpg" width="250" height="150"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.